# Bash script that creates files and gives all possible permisions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-permissions

Here is code that creates files and gives all possible permissions.
The only problem that file names sometimes doesn't much the permission (they have to match).
I do not know why?
Could anyone help to resolve that problem?

```bash
p=( --- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx )  
for u in "${p[@]}"; do 
for g in "${p[@]}"; do 
for o in "${p[@]}"; do
  f="task5/$u$g$o.txt"; touch -- "$f" && chmod "u=$u,g=$g,o=$o" -- "$f" 
done; 
done; 
done
```

Comment: While the answer of the proposed duplicate post,  extensively explaines the how the above code-snipped works, it still contains a small bug.  The command `chmod` does not understand permissions which contain a hyphen (e.g. `--x`). In order to fix this, you need to update the `chmod` command into `chmod "u=${u//-/},g=${g//-/},o=${o//-/}" -- "$f"` where we git rid of all the hyphens. Note that the equal sign, ensures that all permissions are set as requested and all existing permissions are unset if not requested.

Comment: @kvantour thank you a lot. that was the solution!

Comment: IMO, the simplest form would be `chmod ugo+rw "$f"`, or `chmod ugo+rwx "$f"`, if you want executable premissions too. Of course something like `chmod 0777 "$f"` would work too, if you prefer to write the octal pattern.